# Date Picker Date change while using Google Translator

Tags: jquery

I am using Date Picker for the checkin Date.

I am using Google Translator in my website.

So when I change the language from English to Chinese or any other language, 
Date picker value become `NaN/NaN/NaN`. Datepicker format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

add `notranslate` class in `jquery.ui.datepicker.js` with class `ui-helper-clearfix`.

Comment: Yes same described on google site https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/faq#technical

Comment: same solutions also present here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130370/stopping-google-translate-from-translating-datepicker

Answer (score 3):

when you can't / don't want to change the jQuery UI datepicker code, you could also use the beforeShow callback to add the `notranslate` class:

```
beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
    inst.dpDiv.addClass('notranslate');
}
```

tested with version 1.12.0

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to search this

`ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all`

in your jquery ui JS or you can search whole project and than replace all occurrence with

`ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all notranslate`.

keyword `notranslate` will prevent your calendar to translate.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with date picker. It was replacing date with Nan/Nan/Nan. I was using google language translator for the website, I disabled it and it started working properly.

Answer (score 0):

If we translate form with datepicker using Google translate, the field may show NaN/NaN/NaN instead of selected date after compleeting translation.

The Google have solution for it. We need to add notranslate to the field or its parent element. Google translate never consider content within this classs for translation.

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker notranslate">
```

If we are using jQuery & jQuery UI datepicker, we can also add class using jQuery during initialization of datepicker.

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $('.ui-datepicker').addClass('notranslate');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add on focus event
Answer 1

```
$(function () {
$('.datepicker').on('focus', function () {
    $('.datepicker').addClass('notranslate');
});
```

});

OR
Answer 2
add this js file
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js