# Jquery datepicker returns NAN as timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I am using **jquery datepicker** to select a date and convert to timestamp (epoch time). The script works arbitrarily. It shows timestamp for dates from 1st to 12th of any chosen month but makes time 12:00am  of those days (I converted it online). But from 13th to the end of the month it shows **NAN** as timestamp. Strange enough when the date formated to dd/mm/yy all the days shows correctly.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              var dtV = $(this).val();
              var d = new Date(dtV);
              var s = parseInt((d)/1000);
              $("#selectedDate").text("on " + dateText + "");
              $(".selectedDate2").text(s.valueOf());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your case seems like days and months are mixed and the answers provided should solve the problem. However, it might be interesting to mention that in some cases the [reason might be Google Translate](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/nan-nan-nan-with-jquery-datepicker-google-translate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `new Date()`you have to pass a valid date. `dd-mm-yy` is not a valid date for `Date`and it's chenging your month per day.

If you cannot change your date format, try this:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var dtV = $(this).val();
    var exploded=dtV.split("-");
    var d = new Date(exploded[2],exploded[1],exploded[0]);
```

**EDIT**: Better and shorter, use datepicker's `getDate` to get a `Date` object:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var d = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9WMvk/

Answer (score 15):

I had a similar problem: usually the datepicker worked properly, also for dates with the day after the 12th; but from time to time I saw in Google Analytics that a user was getting **NaN-NaN-NaN**.

After investigating, I discovered that it could be [due to Google Translate](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/nan-nan-nan-with-jquery-datepicker-google-translate).

I checked in my analytics the language of the users getting the error. Almost all of them had a language that my website did not support. That was enough to assume that Google Translator was causing the error.

To solve it, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17130585/5802289), add the `notranslate` class:

```
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $('.ui-datepicker').addClass('notranslate');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Following works for me. Just added a **ui-datepicker** class:

```
$(function () {
        $("#txtStartDate").datepicker();
        $('.ui-datepicker').addClass('notranslate');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's interpreting your format as if it's `mm-dd-yy`; JavaScript's native `Date` class assumes all string input in the format `\d\d[-/]\d\d[-/]\d\d` is `mm-dd-yy`.

The `yyyy-mm-dd` format [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is more common and should be interpreted correctly.